# Can passing an action object an empty object upon initialization affect application state?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have this function here that has an action given an empty object:

```
export default reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch(action.type) {
    return {
      ...state, blahblah
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible this could create some type of bug or better framed, why could this be a bad practice? With my understanding of how reducers work, I don't see the point in giving initializing the action with an empty object.

Comment: I dont see the point. Your action creators will always return an object with a type/payload so seems unnecessary to set a default

Comment: @varoons, please free to post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see the point either. Your action creators will(be required to) always return an object with a type/payload so seems unnecessary to set a default